# RegExing a veiwstate

Tags: regex, viewstate

First of all, what is a viewstate?
In testautomation I probably need to correlate this value as it is unique for every user logging in?

How can I get the 'value' / token below using regex?

```
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" value="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" />
```

Comment: you should not parse HTML with regex.

Comment: ...this is why webforms and test-automation don't work well together. MVC-4-life!

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

then if you still want to have a go, use this:

`(?<=input )(?:.*)(value\=\".*\")`